# iText 7 (7.0.2)Error: The method add(AreaBreak) in the type Document is not applicable for the arguments (Paragraph)

Tags: itext7

I am trying to learn iText7(7.0.2), and building a basic pdf, but encountering an error at `document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"))`, saying

> The method add(AreaBreak) in the type Document is not applicable for the arguments (Paragraph)"

Any help will be thankful.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new PdfTest().createPdf(DEST);
}

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    //Initialize PDF writer
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

    //Initialize PDF document
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

    // Initialize document
    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    //Add paragraph to the document
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));

    //Close document
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you import the correct `Paragraph` class? It should be `com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph`

Answer (score 0):

Just run your example. It's work perfectly fine. My best guess is you have old caches from *itextpdf5*. Make sure your *.pom*-file contains only *itext7* dependencies. And, as mkl mentioned in his comment, correct way to import **Paragraph** is

```
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph
```